# Read google spreadsheet using drive sdk

Tags: google-drive-api

Using the new Drive SDK, I would like to read and update rows/columns in a native google spreadsheet stored on my google drive, and display them on my web page. I m using Java and App Engine. I found the documentation and DrEdit example confusing, they don't exactly explain how to read/update native google docs. Can someone please explain to me what I need to do step by step, with code examples if possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The [Google Spreadsheets API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/) would be the better choice for interacting directly with row and column data.

Comment: Is there a way to tie Spreadsheets API in with Drive API? By which I mean, if I have a file ID from Google Drive can I then switch to the Spreadsheets API using the same ID?

Comment: Also using the same oAuth credentials?

Comment: There is no way to do this. You'll need to use the Spreadsheet API and it's OAuth scope.